# Is there such a word as 'tractless' and what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I recall hearing the phrase 'tractless wilderness' but no dictionaries has 'tractless'. Up until now, I believed the meaning to be 'expansive'.

There is a possibility that I'm confusing it with 'trackless', but I don't see how this would convey the same meaning as 'trackless' simply means without tracks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) for the much more common idiom **trackless wilderness**.

Like all the best eggcorns, though, it’s a very plausible reinterpretation, as Martin Beckett’s answer describes, since *tracts* can mean *divisions of land, esp. into properties*, which (like tracks) are something a wilderness would typically lack.

The reinterpretation seems to have arise quite often, as Google [Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22tractless%20wilderness%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1804,cd_max:1918&lr=lang_en) and [ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=trackless+wilderness%2Ctractless+wilderness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) show, going back at least to the early eighteenth century; for instance:

> The difficulty of placing these correctly in a tractless wilderness, which has never been accurately measured, will at once plead both his excuse and mine.

from an [1811 bible commentary](http://books.google.com/books?id=Lds8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA479&dq=%22tractless+wilderness%22&hl=en&ei=KJ_FTZT-HIfKswau7dmHDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22tractless%20wilderness%22&f=false) mapping the travels of the Israelites.

Comment: "She's beautiful, she's rich, she's got huge... tracts of land."

Answer (score 3):

Though 'tractless' could theoretically be a word, I am sure the phrase is 'trackless wilderness', meaning somewhere so wild there aren't even any paths.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you may have heard ***“trackless wilderness”***. In that case, in simply means “with no paths or tracks”.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is tractless, 'tract' is a marked out parcel of land, as in a lot.
So tractless is unplanned, unclaimed wilderness.

Any British English speaker will be familiar with "huge great tracts of land - good pig country"